# Is there a stack exchange graphic design careers site?

Tags: discussion

Do we have Graphic design career option here in stack exchange graphics, like we have in Stack overflow career?

Answer (score 6):

At the moment there is only one ***careers***.

However, and although the focus there is on stackoverflow, if you create a profile your reputation on GD.SE will also be displayed after the work experience area. You can also pick your best questions and answers from any SE site and place them at the bottom.

I've seen and applied for a few design positions through careers in the past, so I'd say: give it a try :)

Comment: Didn't know about this, can you post a link e.g. to your "careers" profile?

Comment: I re-visited my profile and edited the answer a bit. It's very old, but you can see the last bit with the GD stuff: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/68917

Comment: hmm, link doesn't seem to work for me, I guess you need a special (=expensive) employer's account to see people's profiles

Comment: I think there are two types of profiles now. I didn't know! I can only see it if I'm editing it :/